# Ajax runs on local server but not outside

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Ajax looked fine when I dev inside of visual studio.

I just pushed over my aspx's to my server.  When I log in the AJAX controls do not work.

When I view the website locally on the server they do work.

I'm using IIS 7.5 Windows 2008 and also ajax was dev in .net4.0 is there something i'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it or not this was caused by an out of date CSS file, ajax functionality will not happen if your Ajax calls for the css and it's not present.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible the scripts are failing. Which ajax though - built in asp.net, jQuery, etc?
Use fiddler from www.fiddler2.com (debugging proxy) and compare your local request to your server request. See if the scripts come across. Its possible the server is setup in a zone for security purposes isn't allowing javascript (for instance if running physically on the server logged in via console)

This may help shed light on why the script isn't loading - so:
1. ensure the scripts come down from fiddler
2. make sure your security zone in your browser allows for script to execute

Comment: could this be because i have no Register HTTPHandlers in my web.config?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a url problem. Have you checked to make sure that the urls are relative and not absolute?

Or it could be a permissions problem. Make sure the internet guest account has the proper permissions to the folder you want to access that contains the Ajax stuff.